# Retrofit + GSON + Room Parse subobject as one string

Tags: android, kotlin, gson, retrofit, android-room

I'm using an API to retrieve some data, and store them in my app DB using Room, Retrofit2, and GSON.

My data object is as follow:

```kotlin
@Entity(tableName = "department")
data class Department(
    val nom: String,
    @PrimaryKey val code: String,
    val region: String
)
```

And this is what the API returns me

```json
{
  "nom": "Ain",
  "code": "01",
  "region": {
    "code": "84",
    "nom": "Auvergne-Rhône-Alpes"
  }
}
```

I want to transform the response region.nom as the data region field. My actual solution is to make an interface object that can store the response, then a function for mapping this interface to my data object. But i'm pretty sure there is better/cleaner solution to achieve this (like maybe TypeConverter, but can't understand how it works).

Thanks :

Answer (score 0):

Assume your retrofit api response object name "response".You can simply do this :

```
  var department = Department(response.nom,
                response.region.nom)
```

Then just pass the "department" object to room db insert function.